# How can I get started with Microsoft Ink for Mobile?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, compact-framework, .net-2.0, microsoft.ink

We have a simple requirement - to allow drawing on top of a picture and save it.

I've seen an example using an ink control (which I am lead to believe comes with .net) that does exactly what I want, however, no one was able to tell me where to find it or how to include it in my project.

After a lot of googling, I've [found](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb431844.aspx) a [lot](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/e718fd6f-c834-479e-93e8-e3084d83fdba/) of resources but none of them are particularly useful.

Note that we'll need to do this on a windows form running on XP,Vista and 7, (.net 2 & 3.5) and also on the [compact framework 6.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416507.aspx) (not [tablet](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=b46d4b83-a821-40bc-aa85-c9ee3d6e9699&displaylang=en) pc)

This has to be the most hard to find sdk/api/reference that I've ever searched for. Please can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks.

-For compact framework, [this has been suggested](http://community.opennetcf.com/articles/cf/archive/2007/09/28/using-the-opennetcf-mobile-ink-library-for-windows-mobile-6.aspx). How about for .Net2.0 and .Net3.5 (not tablet editions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [article on inking in the CF here](http://community.opennetcf.com/articles/cf/archive/2007/09/28/using-the-opennetcf-mobile-ink-library-for-windows-mobile-6.aspx).  I doubt you're going to have a lot of portability to the desktop, so I'd be inclined to abstract all of the inking work you need to do through an interface and handle the implementation based on the platform.

Comment: I did see this, I understood there were Microsoft controls for this rather than third party?

Comment: As the article points out, the MS control is a COM control, not a managed control.  The code in the article wraps that.

Comment: How about for normal windows apps in .Net2?